# Estimate Scrapy progress by counting start_url calls

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to estimate the progress of a spider by counting how many time `start_url` it has been called but I'm not sure how to detect this.

I realise it's nowhere near a real measure of current progress as the spider has no clue how big the remaining sites to be crawled are.

Any ideas on how to get the execution count of `start_urls`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you might be able to accomplish this through the use of signals. Specifically, the item_scraped signal which allows you to register an event after an item is scraped. For each received response, check if the response.url is in the start_url list.

```
scrapy.signals.item_scraped(item, response, spider)
```

More info on the scrapy docs page: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html

Comment: Care to elaborate how that would help me detect when the spider moves from one start_url to another? item_scraped will trigger multiple times within the same start_url scope so I'm not sure how I would use that event?

Comment: Response.url will specify what url the response came from. Check if this url is in the start_url list and have a counter whenever you get a response from a new start_url

Comment: Yeah that was my plan to begin with, store previous value and count when new. Was hoping there would be a more proper way of doing it :) Are there any benefits to using "item_scraped" rather than doing the "start_url" check in my parse_item function?

Comment: Using a signal to process a recurring event is the proper way.